# Prevent alert tone when scanning / identifying an NFC intent

Tags: android, alert, nfc

Perhaps I'm missing something but when I scan an NFC tag via a galaxy nexus, the phone always makes the default alert tone.

Is there a way of programmatically switching this off ? I have scoured the menus / preferences and can't find a way of doing this. The next step ... ICS source code :-/

Comment: You'll probably have better luck with this question on http://android.stackexchange.com. This of course assumes you haven't rooted your phone.

Comment: Heh.. android.stackexchange.com said "go to stackoverflow.com"... Good job I can spot a recursion. Phone not rooted as I want to put this into the app for non-rooted phones...

Comment: What I was trying to get at was: If this option to turn off the tone really doesn't exist within the _regular_ settings (and you verified this on android.stackexchange.com), then there's a very good chance you won't be able to do it programatically. The rooted phone comment applies to the latter.

Comment: FWIW. I have raised this on the android code base feature request list : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24022

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't a way to pro grammatically turn this sound off or to override the Touch to Beam UI.

Comment: It's now possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908374/android-nfc-enable-and-disable-the-nfc-detected-sounds

Answer (score 6):

with android-19 you can:

as described in:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS

By using NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode() and the flag FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS instead of NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()

Comment: Please read [answer] and provide the useful informations from the link in the answer. If the link dies, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example of how to silence/change nfc sounds

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ReaderCallback{
private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // This example works using using simple mifare ultralight tags. Set any necessary flags for other tags 
    mNfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, this, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS, null);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mNfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);
}

@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
    // Play your own sound here

    // Then handle your tag
}
```

}