# Android NFC: enable and disable the NFC detected sounds

Tags: android, tags, nfc, system-sounds

I am dealing with NFC tags. My problem is that I cannot turn off the sound when NFC tags are detected. I started my research and also started getting  confused:

- [Turn off device's NFC sound](https://forum.nfcring.com/topic/528/turn-off-device-s-nfc-sound)
- [Prevent alert tone when scanning / identifying an NFC intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743588/prevent-alert-tone-when-scanning-identifying-an-nfc-intent)
- [How do I disable/change the NFC sounds?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/how-do-i-disable-change-the-nfc-sounds)

Some say that we can and some that we can't disable those sounds.

Can we disable and enable the NFC sound programmatically?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Starting with API level 19 (Android 4.4) you can disable the NFC sounds while your app is in the foreground by using the newer reader-mode API to listen for NFC tags. The reader-mode API has a flag `FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS` that can be used to disable the NFC discovery sounds.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    adapter.enableReaderMode(this,
            new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onTagDiscovered(final Tag tag) {
                    // do something
                }
            },
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A |
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F |
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V |
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE |
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
            null);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: For some strange reason this didn't work. But putting the FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS first on tags seemed to do the trick :)

Comment: perfect solution i was looking for. thanks

Comment: Thank  you for your answer Michael. How can I transact APDUs from/to card using this code? `IsoDep` is not working for me!